# Delete hosted zones in Route53 using boto3

Tags: boto3, amazon-route53, destroy, zone

I need to delete all those hosted zones in Route53 using boto3

I created the zones in AWS console and trying to delete all those zones using boto3 using lamda function. I used the below codes however it throws error

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Iterate over regions
    for region in regions:

        # Running following for a particular region
        print ("*************** Checking region  --   %s " % region['RegionName'])
        reg=region['RegionName']


        ########### cleaning Route53 zones ################

        client = boto3.client('route53',region_name=reg)
        response = client.list_hosted_zones_by_name()
        for zone in response ['hosted-zones']:
            print ("About to delete %s | in %s" % (zone['HostedZone'], region['RegionName']))
            result = client.delete_hosted_zone(HostedZone=zone['HostedZone'])
```

Getting the following error message:

```
'hosted-zones': KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 22, in lambda_handler
    for zone in response ['hosted-zones']:
KeyError: 'hosted-zones'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your python `KeyError` is giving you the information: there is no key `hosted-zones` on the client response object; the key you are looking for is `HostedZones`. See the [boto3 Route53 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/route53.html#Route53.Client.list_hosted_zones_by_name) which contains the response syntax. The key `HostedZone` also does not exist at that level of the response object, you need to use `Id`. The [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/route53.html#Route53.Client.delete_hosted_zone) for `boto3` is pretty good for this kind of thing!

```
for zone in response['HostedZones']:
    client.delete_hosted_zone(Id=zone['Id'])
```

Comment: It would be great If you give me the valid syntax..since I am new to boto3 I am not much aware of it.

Comment: `Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteHostedZone operation: The resource hostedzone/Z22MQQMFU2EPN9 can only be managed through servicediscovery.amazonaws.com (arn:aws:servicediscovery:us-east-1:695121473358:namespace/ns-vax34g7lbqxcsuyp)",
  "errorType": "ClientError"`  .---getting new error

Comment: yeah you can run into problems with private hosted zones with servicediscovery, see for example https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=279241 but you'll probably need to ask a new SO question

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/servicediscovery.html#ServiceDiscovery.Client.delete_service is how you can do it with `boto`